# SQL server covering index

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to design a table that is going to have around 60 million records,    Table is partitioned and I have around 15 columns and search will be done based on 4 or 5 columns, I created non clustered  index on those columns, but getting Key  lookup, is it good to have covering index on all remaining columns?

Comment: Could be. Depends on your workload and whether the benefit of avoiding the lookups outweighs the additional costs of maintaining the wider index.

Comment: Martin pointed out in his earlier comment,it depends

Comment: A RID lookup suggests you have no clustered index. Consider creating a a clustered index, which will implicitly include the clustered index key in non-clustered index to facilitate covering.

Comment: @DanGuzman,   I created clustered index on ID(identity field), but no searches will be done on this field,   I don't have any other unique field to create index, is that good?

Comment: You could try a nonclustered Columnstore index on those 5 columns.

Comment: @user8179431, the clustered index key does not need to be unique and can include multiple columns.